# Asterisk Auto dial out issues

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm trying to make auto dial out in asterisk.I have created call file in /tmp directory and moved the file to **"var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/"**

It's not working. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Call File

```
Channel: SIP/700
MaxRetries: 2
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: call-file-test
```

extensions_custom.conf

```
[call-file-test]
exten => S,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Error Log

```
[2015-04-12 11:05:24] NOTICE[4397]: pbx_spool.c:388 attempt_thread: Call failed to go through, reason (0) Call Failure (not BUSY, and not NO_ANSWER, maybe Circuit busy or down?)               
[2015-04-12 11:05:24] NOTICE[4397]: pbx_spool.c:391 attempt_thread: Queued call to SIP/700 expired without completion after 2 attempts
```

Comment: Is your SIP user with extension 700 is registered in asterisk server and live?

Comment: Yes. It's already registered with asterisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your SIP user extension 700 is registered into asterisk server and is live
Execute the following command in asterisk server

```
asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'
```

It will display all the sip users currently live and registered into the asterisk server.Do not forget to give 777 permission to your call file and

```
chown asterisk:asterisk your_call_file.call
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have run the command "asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'". It's showing the below output.                `[root@Asterisk ~]# asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description
0 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 0 offline]
` But i have already registered the 700 extension.

Comment: It's working for me after changing the call file conf  From `Channel: SIP/701` to `Channel: PJSIP/701`